# How to addSubview to NSSrollView correctly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scroller: NSScrollView!

var showSettingsButton = NSButton(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 860, 60, 40))
    showSettingsButton.title = "Settings"
    scroller.addSubview(showSettingsButton)
```

The button looks as intended by the scrollview keeps static, but when I scroll the ScrollView, the button just looks like this:

[image]

I want to put this button always in the down-left corner regardless of scroller's scrolling.
So which view should be the superView of this button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be in your `View`. Put it underneath the `Scroll View - Text View`, but make sure it will be siblings with the `Scroll View - Text View`, and not a child.
If you're going to add it in code, add it like

```
view.addSubview(showSettingsButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement , you should subclass NSScrollView and override the "tile" method. There you can specify your buttons frame

Answer (score 0):

When you want your `Button` not to scroll, why do you add it to the scroll view then?

Add it to `view`, the superview of `scrollview`. So make it a sibling of the `scrollview`. Just add the `scrolliview` first and the `button` next so that the `button` overwrites the `scrollview` and appears on top.

```
ViewController 
-> View
   -> ScrollView
      -> TextView (and anything that you want to scroll)
   -> Button
```

You may want to do parts of this programmatically because IB or Storyboard Editor respectivey may change the view hierarchy again by making the button a subview of your scroll view.